# Ubuntu 17.10 Screen Flickering after Unlock

Tags: display, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome, lock-screen

Since I reinstalled Ubuntu I've been having an issue where sometimes, after locking and then returning to the PC later and unlocking, the screen flickers continuously, or remains white. The only way I can fix it is my restarting (which I often do by using the console "blind").

This wasn't an issue that I had when i had Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, however, I'm now using 17.10, so wondering if it's a GNOME issue. Not really sure where to star,t so please let me know what extra details you need from me to be able to assist.

The PC is a [Gigabyte Brix BXi3-5010 Ultra Compact](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00T2FJVEU/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1) "sporting" 8GB of RAM, and a 60GB SSD.

Thanks all for any assists.

Comment: I'm still on 16.04 LTS so can't help. I just wanted to comment how cool your little black box is. I also noticed it's sold out around the world on many e-retailer websites.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix that model is about 2 years old now. There are plenty of the more recent models still in stock. :)

Comment: are you using the proprietary intel drivers ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl I believe so, yes. `lshw -c video` states I'm using HD Graphics 5500, which is made by Intel.

Comment: It could be helpful looking at your Xorg log and dmesg when that happens.

Comment: Thanks @velix I'll have a look at them next time it occurs and update.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but a workaround:

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to change to another ..console?
2. Suspend the computer. I close my lid.
3. Wake up, and it is solved.

This works for me. I experience the problem in Ubuntu 17.10, kernel 4.13.0-25-generic, x86_64, using Gnome classic under Xorg.

Comment: Thanks. The PC didn't do it last night, **however** i didn't have Firefox open, and I *think* that might be part of the issue. I intentionally left it open last night, but a work around is better than nothing (a fix would be great however).

Comment: Well, when it happened (4 times already?) I had a few Firefox windows opened, with a lot of tabs in each one, so maybe that is related..

Comment: Just happened again after automatic screen turn off. Took screenshots but they appear normal. Solved it with Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to unity. Log off, then click the GNOME foot icon and select "Unity" (Not the second one.) Log on, and reboot. If not, stay on Unity and re-install GNOME using (adding repository is not needed unless not done on newest vesion):

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Source (of package names): https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-gnome-38-on-ubuntu/